# Mysql - WHERE multiple values with same identifier

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to solve problem. This is my query>

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM `ps_product` p 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` AND pl.id_shop = 1 ) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute` pa ON (pa.`id_product` = p.`id_product`) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute_combination` pac ON (pac.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`) 

WHERE pl.`id_lang` = 2 
AND p.`id_category_default` = 25 
AND p.`active` = 1 
AND pac.`id_attribute` = 1714 
AND pac.`id_attribute` = 1736 
AND pac.`id_attribute` = 1737 
AND pac.`id_attribute` = 216 

ORDER BY p.`price` ASC
```

My problem is selecting only products which are containing all 4 id_attributes.

Table ps_product_attribute_combination contains two columns. id_product_attribute and id_attribute. For example>

```
id_attribute  /  id_product_attribute
1714             120
1736             120
1737             120
216              120
```

I hope explanation is succesfull :)
Thanks!

Comment: Well it can't be 1714  **AND** 1736, use an IN: `AND pac.id_attribute IN (1714, 1736, 1737, 216)`

Comment: IN isn't working. It has to have all 4. IN will work even if doesn't contain all 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join four times, one for each attribute you want the product to have:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM `ps_product` p 
JOIN `ps_product_lang` pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` AND pl.id_shop = 1 ) 
JOIN `ps_product_attribute` pa ON (pa.`id_product` = p.`id_product`) 
JOIN `ps_product_attribute_combination` pac1 ON (pac1.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`) 
JOIN `ps_product_attribute_combination` pac2 ON (pac2.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`) 
JOIN `ps_product_attribute_combination` pac3 ON (pac3.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`) 
JOIN `ps_product_attribute_combination` pac4 ON (pac4.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`) 

WHERE pl.`id_lang` = 2 
AND p.`id_category_default` = 25 
AND p.`active` = 1 
AND pac1.`id_attribute` = 1714 
AND pac2.`id_attribute` = 1736 
AND pac3.`id_attribute` = 1737 
AND pac4.`id_attribute` = 216 

ORDER BY p.`price` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM `ps_product` p 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` AND pl.id_shop = 1 ) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute` pa ON (pa.`id_product` = p.`id_product`) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute_combination` pac ON (pac.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`) 

WHERE pl.`id_lang` = 2 
AND p.`id_category_default` = 25 
AND p.`active` = 1 
AND 
    (
        pac.`id_attribute` = 1714 
        OR 
        pac.`id_attribute` = 1736 
        OR 
        pac.`id_attribute` = 1737 
        OR 
        pac.`id_attribute` = 216 
    )

ORDER BY p.`price` ASC
```

Comment: Yes, I misread your question. RSanchez' approach is the right one.